# Expand All Variables Inside Add_Click Inside Function

Tags: winforms, powershell

```
$TextApp1 = "it works"

function DrawButton {

    $Temp = "$args"

    $ButtonType = Get-Variable -Name "Button$Temp" -Value

    $ButtonType | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{ DataTemp = $Temp }

    $ButtonType.Add_Click({
        $Data = $($this.DataTemp)
        $DefaultForm.Text = "$Data"
    })

    $DefaultGroupBox.Controls.Add($ButtonType)

}

DrawButton App1
```

it works now thanks to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)

this has gotten me one step closer to making things easier to manage you have no clue how much you helped

~2,000 lines of code turned into ~50 and i dont haveto remake 50 lines of code everytime i wanna make a button now

Comment: Can you add a reference, explaining what are  $DefaultForm,   $DefaultGroupBox?

Comment: `$DefaultForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form`
`$DefaultGroupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the event handler runs in a child scope of the *script* scope, not of your function's scope, so it doesn't see the `$Temp` variable.
In other words: there is no closure that would capture the value of `$Temp` and make it available in the event handler.

While it is possible to set variables in the script scope with scope specifier `$script:`, this is generally to be avoided and in your case wouldn't give you separate values that are specific to each invocation of `DrawButton`.

Your best bet is to attach the desired value to the button object as a *custom property*, using `Add-Member`:

```
function DrawButton {

    $Temp = "$args"

    $ButtonType = Get-Variable -Name "Button$Temp" -Value

    # Add the value of $Temp as custom property .CustomProperty to the
    # button object.
    $ButtonType | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{ CustomProperty = $Temp }

    $ButtonType.Add_Click({
        # $this refers to the button object; extract the custom property's value
        $DefaultForm.Text = "Text$($this.CustomProperty)"
    })

    $DefaultGroupBox.Controls.Add($ButtonType)
    $ButtonType.Cursor = $HandCursor

}
```

Comment: works perfectly thank you, having to reset all my variables inside the click event is kinda weird but very nice thank you

Answer (score -1):

I think that your issue is related that you declare $button locally instead of globally to live after DrawButton is called.
Unfortunately PowerShell doesn’t have good way to force declarations [Is there an "Option Explicit" in PowerShell?](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/there-option-explicit-powershell)

Also you probably have incorrect types.
 $ButtonType is initialized as a string, but then you use it ButtonType.Add_Click as a button.

Anyway learn how to debug your code (e.g. using Visual Studio Code or PowerGui) and you will be able to find the answers yourself.

Comment: `$ButtonType` isn't initialized as a string; it is set to the value of a preexisting variable named `"Button$Temp"`, presumed to be a WinForms _button object_ (even though the OP's code doesn't show that explicitly). That `$ButtonType` is a _local_ variable is unrelated to the problem, because it is only used to manipulate the _referenced object_.